# Android custom bar not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am using this code to implement a Custom Action bar but the app crashes. I am using layout inflator to return a view of custom layout and then applying it to action bar.

Here is custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:background="#00897B" >


<Button
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register an event"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="#4db6ac"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/refr"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
    LayoutInflater l=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v1=l.inflate(R.layout.custom,null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v1);

}


}
```

**Here is the error when app crashes:**

```
 Process: com.khurana.nikhil.navigationdrawer, PID: 2255
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.khurana.nikhil.navigationdrawer/com.khurana.nikhil.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setCustomView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.khurana.nikhil.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

Comment: Which android version of emulator/device you are using for this?

Comment: I am currently using my Samsung Note II which has got kitkat version.(API 19)

Answer (score 0):

You have lost

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.someView);
```

Try to user getSupportActionBar() instead getActionBar().

If this does not help, try to change app theme in Styles, maybe you use NoActionBar theme

**updated**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
            actionBar.setCustomView(v1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Currently i am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme....and `getSupportActionBar()` doesn't work

Comment: Try to add super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); to your onCreate method

Comment: Try to use code, that i provide in update. 
It work fine on my device

Comment: @NikhilKhurana Hope updated answer should work. Please check this.

Comment: Also, get rid of ActionBar, Try with ToolBar.

Comment: @noundla doesn't work .... :(   `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`  gives error `required :android.app.ActionBar   Found:android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Comment: @noundla this worked. I imported `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;` . But the customview doesn't overrides action bar

Answer (score 0):

How you tried setting your theme to a theme that supports the ActionBar, like `Theme.Holo.Light?`

Also, in your Activity you can try `getActionBar().show();`

Comment: show() doesn't worked....I changed the theme from the option that appears on top of virtual device in layout file...There's an option app theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Principale extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ecran_d_acceuil);


}
public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principale, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

Try this.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? And what principale? if it is mainactivity as in my case,then it doesn;t work